# C# WASM Encryption/Decryption using JS Interop error: Unhandled exception rendering component

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, interop, webassembly

I'm having some issues when I try to decrypt a string in c# wasm using js interop. I'm new to encryption/decryption so I am unsure of what the error is actually saying. I have stepped through my code and logged the keys, iv and other items and seems they are the proper values.

Here is the code I have.

Blazor page

Encryption.razor

```
<div class="input-container">
    <label for="plainText">Input string</label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input id="plainText" type="text" @bind="plainText" title="Input string" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button-container">
    <button @onclick="Encrypt" class="button-style button-one">Encrypt</button>
    <button @onclick="Decrypt" class="button-style">Decrypt</button>
</div>

<div class="input-container">
    <label for="encryptedMessage">Encrypted/Decrypted Message</label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input id="encryptedMessage" type="text" @bind="encryptedMessage" />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private string plainText = "";
    private string encryptedMessage = "";
    private string keyBase64 = "";
    private string ivBase64 = "";

    // Method to generate a key and IV
    private async Task GenerateKeyAndIV()
    {
        keyBase64 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("generateKey");
        ivBase64 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("generateIV");
    }

    private async Task Encrypt()
    {
        await GenerateKeyAndIV();
        encryptedMessage = await encryptionService.Encrypt(plainText, keyBase64, ivBase64);
    }

    private async Task Decrypt()
    {
        await GenerateKeyAndIV();
        plainText = await encryptionService.Decrypt(encryptedMessage, keyBase64, ivBase64);
    }

    // Call GenerateKeyAndIV when the component is initialized
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GenerateKeyAndIV();
    }
```

EncryptionService.cs

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class EncryptionService
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

    public EncryptionService(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    }

    public async Task<string> Encrypt(string text, string keyBase64, string iv)
    {
        return await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("encryptText", text, keyBase64, iv);
    }

    public async Task<string> Decrypt(string encryptedBase64, string keyBase64, string iv)
    {
        return await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("decryptText", encryptedBase64, keyBase64, iv);
    }
}
```

index.html scripts

```
<script>
      window.generateKey = async () => {
          const key = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
              { name: 'AES-GCM', length: 128 },
              true,
              ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
          );
          const keyBytes = await crypto.subtle.exportKey('raw', key);
          return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(keyBytes)));
      };
</script> 

<!-- Function to generate IV -->
<script>
window.generateIV = async () => {
    const iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, iv));
};
</script>

<!-- Function to encrypt text using AES-GCM algorithm -->
<script>
  async function encryptText(text, keyBase64, ivBase64) {
      const iv = new Uint8Array(atob(ivBase64).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
      const keyBytes = new Uint8Array(atob(keyBase64).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
      const encodedText = new TextEncoder().encode(text);
      const encodedKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", keyBytes, "AES-GCM", false, ["encrypt"]);
      const encryptedBytes = await crypto.subtle.encrypt({ name: "AES-GCM", iv }, encodedKey, encodedText);
      return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(encryptedBytes)));
  }
</script>

<!-- Function to decrypt text using AES-GCM algorithm -->
<script>
  async function decryptText(encryptedBase64, keyBase64, ivBase64) {
      const iv = new Uint8Array(atob(ivBase64).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
      const keyBytes = new Uint8Array(atob(keyBase64).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
      const encryptedBytes = new Uint8Array(atob(encryptedBase64).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
      const importedKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", keyBytes, "AES-GCM", false, ["decrypt"]);
      const decryptedBytes = await crypto.subtle.decrypt({ name: "AES-GCM", iv }, importedKey, encryptedBytes);
      return new TextDecoder().decode(decryptedBytes);
  }
</script>
```

I have logged the values and they seem correct. I have tried consulting chatGPT on the error but it doesn't specificy what exactly the issue is in the decrypt function.

[image: error msg]

Comment: It looks like `GenerateKeyAndIV()` is called during *both* `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()`. This would mean that key and IV are different during encryption and decryption, which would cause the decryption to fail.

Comment: Wow I must have missed that, it's not throwing the error anymore but it's also not showing the decrypted message, but I think that's just an issue with me displaying it. Thanks so much! @Topaco